# Mysql event not working in the server. Same code worked in local

Tags: events, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

```
DROP EVENT `game_insert`; CREATE DEFINER=`numberBetting_user`@`%` EVENT `game_insert` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2021-08-18 17:25:29' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN UPDATE `game` set `status` =0 where `status`=1; INSERT INTO `game`(`startTime`, `endTime`,`status`,`betting`) VALUES (now(),NOW() + INTERVAL 5 minute,1,1); END
```

This event would insert a record every 5 minutes. It was working fine in local(xampp) but in the live server, it is not inserting data. Though event scheduler is on.

[image]

Everything looks fine but the event is not doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

Add DELIMITER like below

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP EVENT `game_insert`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`numberBetting_user`@`%` EVENT `game_insert` ON 
SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2021-08-18 17:25:29' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
BEGIN 
UPDATE `game` set `status` =0 where `status`=1;
 INSERT INTO `game`(`startTime`, `endTime`,`status`,`betting`) VALUES (now(),NOW() + INTERVAL 5 minute,1,1); 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Only when you are in mysql workbench, you don't need thejm because they are added automatically

Comment: Now I am getting the following error message "Unrecognized statement type. (near "END" at position 352)"

Comment: have you copied the text or only added text to your code? my code throws no error

Comment: "I removed the DROP EVENT `game_insert`; " and created the event. But still not working

Comment: it runs on m< side and on dbfiddle in mysql 5.7 and mysql 8.0 see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=742eec780a1410388afeabbb94231586

Comment: dbfiddle doens't need any DELIMTER it adds it automatically too

Comment: I am using mariaDB 10.3 and in dbfiddle my code runs @nbk

Comment: there maybe a character or something please colpy the code from the answer diretly in phpmyadmin or whatever you are using

Comment: Tried it. The event got created but it is not doing its job

Comment: i can' see why not, have you updated the column manually and see if it is changed back and check with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-events.html

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED the issue. The problem was with my insert query that I was missing a value for a not null column. After I added the value in the insert query the event works fine. Thank you